# Permission Denied with Grunt Compass

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, mkdir, permission-denied

I'm trying to run a Grunt Compass task and it keeps failing with:

> Errno::EACCES on line ["250"] of
>   /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb: Permission denied
>   @ dir_s_mkdir - /stylesheets

My task is:

```
compass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
        require: ['susy', 'breakpoint'],
        sassDir: '<%= paths.srcAssets %>/stylesheets',
        cssDir: '<%= paths.build %>/stylesheets',
        generatedImagesDir: '<%= paths.build %>/images',
        imagesDir: '<%= paths.srcAssets %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= paths.srcAssets %>/javascripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= paths.srcAssets %>/fonts',
        // importPath: ['<%= paths.vendor %>/components'],
        httpImagesPath: '/assets/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/assets/images',
        httpFontsPath: '/assets/fonts',
        sourcemap: true,
        relativeAssets: false,
        noLineComments: true,
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
        raw: 'preferred_syntax = :sass\n',
        environment: 'development',
        bundleExec: true,
        app: 'stand_alone',
        debugInfo: true,
        quiet: false,
        trace: true
    }
  }
},
```

I'm assuming it's failing as it doesn't have the correct permissions to create the 'stylesheets' directory.

This confuses me in two ways:

1. I have another grunt task that successfully creates an 'images' directory in the same location that Compass is trying to place the 'stylesheets' one.
2. I am running this in a Vagrant virtual machine so unsure what the permissions on the parent folder should be.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Neil

Comment: I have a few questions if you are still working on this:

 - Are you interactively working with it, or is this part of an automated CI flow?
 - Have you tried manually creating the 'stylesheets' folder, at least check if that is the only problem?
 - Does grunt successfully write out other files, and create other folders prior to running the compass task?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Thought no one was gonna help. Thanks so much. I am working interactively. I have tried making the folder and it still fails. I will test your last point shortly and get back to you shortly.

Comment: @JamesWing You're right, Tried copying files using a copy task and that fails when trying to make an "images" directory.  Any ideas?

Comment: It does suggest a general permissions issue.  Do you have admin rights on the VM? I'm not sure what the permission should be either, I recommend starting with a limited change just to your output folder, <%= paths.build %> from the Gruntfile.  Something like `chmod -v -v -R u+w outputFolderName` would give you write permission, recursively, and list the files modified.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. Before I do though, If I change the permissions through the VM, is this changing them on my local machine too? This is also confusing me.

Comment: I don't know.  Most VMs have virtual disks, and the permissions would then be contained in the virtual environment.  It is possible that your VM mounts a remote drive, and that might not be the case.  You probably need help from a SysAdmin that understands the VM environment.

Comment: @JamesWing Ok, a couple of updates. Still not working. The permissions on the "assets" directory (from the VM POV) `drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   170 Oct 23 21:07 assets`   Still no idea why it wont work. I ran the command you posted but to no effect.

Comment: Can you post the entire content of your Gruntfile?

Comment: @JamesWing Sorry for the delay. My Gruntfile can be found here: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/4ecbdf6a2dbd6b2f4778   I am running `grunt stylesheets` when I am getting the problems.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that compass try to create the `stylesheets` directory at the `/` of your system, which is obviously forbidden.

This issue is caused by the path you referenced in your `compass` task for the `cssDir` and `imageDir` options:

```
cssDir: '<%= paths.build %>/stylesheets'
```

In your `paths` configuration object, there is no `build` property, but surely a `buildAssets` one, so `<%= paths.build %>` is replaced by null and explain your error.

So just replace the occurences and you should be good to go.

Comment: Dont call you that, we all make mistakes :)

Comment: When I run `grunt stylesheets` I now get: grunt stylesheets
Running "clean:all" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "copy:images" (copy) task
Warning: Unable to create directory "/vagrant/rails/public/assets" (Error code: EEXIST). Use --force to continue.

I've updated my Gruntfile on Gist at: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/4ecbdf6a2dbd6b2f4778

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use the `force` option of your clean task to delete the folders when cleaning or the one of compass to override files

Comment: Could you check the gist now as I ahve added my console output when used with --force. I'm getting rather confused as to why this is all going wrong. I check before I run grunt and the assets directory set as buildAssets is totally empty.  Gist is: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/4ecbdf6a2dbd6b2f4778

Thanks

Comment: You should set `force` option of compass to true not using the `--force` flag

Comment: I did try that, I tried adding force: true to the copy task, the clean task and the compass task. I also tried with --force. Same results.

Comment: Could you try to run compass before your image copy task and to change your `clean:all` to target `"<%= paths.buildAssets %>/"` ?

Comment: Tried that and no change. All in gist has been updated: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/4ecbdf6a2dbd6b2f4778

Comment: Does running only clean:all delete correctly the `public/assets` folder?

Comment: I just made a new cleanall task that only runs "clean:all" and this runs and shows "cleaned 0 paths" so I don't think it is working. I tried creating the assets directory and putting a subdirectory and a file in there and it doesn't remove them when I run the task.

Comment: Maybe you should also try to remove all it's content with `<%= paths.buildAssets %>/**/*` ?

Comment: It's really odd, No change with that either. I had actually tried that before but it still states 0 paths cleaned

Comment: I just navigated to the public directory through my VM and listed contents and it shows assets as being "?????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ? assets"   What does this mean?

Comment: Oaw I don't know :/ Can you remove everything manually and retry ?

Comment: If I manually delete the assets directory via the host machine and recreate it on the host machine, it stills shows up from the VM POV with those strange permissions.

Comment: Made some progress on this. I was looking at this page: http://www.code-experience.com/some-vagrant-gotchas/

And it seems that by adding `:mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=766"]` to my synced folders line in my vagrant file, it is solving the issues I am experiencing. Paths are cleaning and Compass is starting to compile and images are being copied.

I'll leave this open for a short while until I can fully confirm everything is working but thanks for your help so far!!!

Comment: Oh glad you find a way out! I was running out of ideas ;)

Comment: @rctneil Are you still experiencing issues with this?

Comment: No, this seems to be sorted. I thankyou so much for your help but I am undecided about whether to accept this as the answer. My issues being that you correctly found my typos related to paths. No issue there, but nothing referring to the permissions in vagrant. This is in no way underappreciating your help though. What do you think?

Comment: @rctneil Hum that's your call but like you say since the second error referenced by your comments was not caused by valgrant, you should accept that and maybe self answer a new question about this specific issue.